# How does the Windows 10 picture password work?

Tags: passwords, windows

I have been researching on how Windows 10 built their picture password, but there is not much content online.

Can anyone here help explain how the picture authentication system in windows 10 works?

Answer (score -1):

Identifies certain elements in the users face that appropriately matches the saved hash of the owners system. It removes the need to use passwords which users previously had to recall or write down and improves the user experience of its customers.

Windows doc explains it more. Here is a quick link:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/windows-hello-face-authentication

Comment: I guess OP meant a different login method, see this link: https://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-create-login-pin-code-or-picture-password-windows-10